# Why are my background images so big and stretched out?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is how it looks like right now:

[image]

The strange thing is that the image seems to be stretching all the way off the screen.

It should look like this:

[image]

I'm using [stellar.js](http://markdalgleish.com/projects/stellar.js/) a jquery plugin to make background images scroll at a different speed than the content. But I'm not sure if that's the problem. Anyway, here's the CSS:

```
.large-bg-1 {
background: url(images/large-bg-1.jpg) repeat 0 0;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-position: 50% 0;
position: relative;
height: 294px;
width: 100%;
}
```

And the live site: http://www.hfwebdesign.com/?ModPagespeed=off

What can I do to bring the image back to it's original size. Or at least, making it smaller?

Comment: Have you tried `background-size: 100%;`??

Comment: If you still want to keep `background-size: cover`, why don't you edit the background image size manually in photoshop(for example) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `background-size: 100%;`

**For Instance,**

```
.large-bg-1 {
background: url(images/large-bg-1.jpg) repeat 0 0;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
-webkit-background-size: 100%;
-moz-background-size: 100%;
-o-background-size: 100%;
background-size: 100%;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-position: 50% 0;
position: relative;
height: 294px;
width: 100%;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Change the class to this, it will fix the size of the background.

```
.large-bg-1 {
    background: url("images/large-bg-1.jpg") no-repeat fixed 50% 0 / 100% transparent;
    height: 294px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
```

[See doc here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size#Values)

Answer (score 0):

You can try using

```
background-size: 100% 100%;
```

Link : http://www.css3.info/preview/background-size/

Comment: So, what's the difference with `background-size: 100%` as Nathan Lee said??

Comment: background-size: 100% 100%; it will adjust the image width as 100% and height 100% of the containing element’s width and height.    background-size: 100%; it will adjust the image width as 100% of the containing element’s width and height of the image will adjust proportionately to the width to maintain proper aspect ratio.